# Checking the type of a json property

Tags: json, postgresql-9.3

I'm looking for a way to verify the type of a json variable in PostgreSQL.
Here's what I mean:

```
get_type('"s"'::josn)  => 'string'
get_type('1'::json)    => 'number'
get_type('2.3'::json)  => 'number'
get_type('null'::json) => 'null'
get_type('[]'::json)   => 'array'
get_type('{}'::json)   => 'object'
```

I'm looking for the `get_type` function.

Comment: In 9.4 there's `jsonb_typeof`. I don't think there's an equivalent for the plain `json` type, which is all that's available in 9.3.

Comment: @CraigRinger That's great but then what happens to the functions provided for `json` and not `jsonb`? I mean something like `array_to_json`! Does that mean I have to cast between the two back and forth?

Comment: @CraigRinger I just tested and there's also `json_typeof` function accepting a `json`! That will do thanks.

Comment: Great. I must've missed it in the listing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `json_typeof` (or `jsonb_typeof` for 9.4's `jsonb`). Despite being [missing from the 9.3 documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) it's apparently present, and is documented in the [manual for json functions in 9.4 and above](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html).