# How to make sure that a jsonb object is not an encoded string?

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have found sometimes a jsonb object:

```
{"a": 1, "b": 2}
```

will get re-encoded and stored as a jsonb string:

```
"{\"a\": 1, \"b\": 2}"
```

is there a way to write a function that will reparse the string when input is not a jsonb object?

Comment: To check the type, here a useful answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732471/checking-the-type-of-a-json-property. And to re-encode it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41924784/how-do-i-convert-text-to-jsonb

Comment: thanks. those links were really good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#>>` operator (*Extracts JSON sub-object at the specified path as text*) does the job:

```sql
select ('"{\"a\": 1, \"b\": 2}"'::jsonb #>> '{}')::jsonb
```

This operator behavior is not officially documented. It appears to be a side effect of its underlying function. Oddly enough, its twin operator `#>` doesn't work that way, though it would be even more logical. It's probably worth asking Postgres developers to solve this, preferably by adding a new decoding function. While waiting for a system solution, you can define a simple SQL function to make queries clearer in cases where the problem occurs frequently.

```sql
create or replace function jsonb_unescape(text)
returns jsonb language sql immutable as $$
    select ($1::jsonb #>> '{}')::jsonb
$$;
```

Note that the function works well both on escaped and plain strings:

```sql
with my_data(str) as (
values
    ('{"a": 1, "b": 2}'),
    ('"{\"a\": 1, \"b\": 2}"')
)
select str, jsonb_unescape(str)
from my_data;

          str           |  jsonb_unescape
------------------------+------------------
 {"a": 1, "b": 2}       | {"a": 1, "b": 2}
 "{\"a\": 1, \"b\": 2}" | {"a": 1, "b": 2}
(2 rows)
```